# Sort records by date and count number of repeated users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Suppose I have users `A` and `B` and they create some items in the database. When **ordered by creation date**, they look like this:

```
items = A, A, A, B, B, A, B, B
```

That is, `A` creates 3 items, then `B` creates 2, then `A` creates 1, and finally `B` creates 2 more.

I want to count the number of **continuously repeated** user ids while **preserving the ordering**, this is what I want as the result:

```
repeats = [{A: 3}, {B: 2}, {A: 1}, {B: 2}]
```

How do I do a count like this with a ActiveRecord query? My database is Postgres.

I tried a combination of `group(:user_id)` and `count(:user_id)` but it doesn't work when also using `order(created_at: :desc)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided that a pure SQL-based solution is too complicated in this case. Once you factor in some additional query conditions, entire thing will become too difficult to understand and maintain. Therefore I have decided to just implement the counting in application logic.

Below is a sample of how I've implemented it. It's quite straightforward.

```
items = Item.where(condition1, condition2, ...)
            .order(created_at: :desc)
            .select(:user_id)
            .limit(n)

repeats = []
current_user_id, current_count = nil

items.each do |i|
  if current_user != i.user_id
     repeats << { i.user_id: current_count } if current_count.present?
     current_user = i.user_id
     current_count = 0
  else
     current_count += 1
  end
end
```

*Note: Simplified code to demonstrate logic, might not actually run.*

Answer (score 2):

One method of doing this uses the difference of row numbers method:

```
select t, count(*) as cnt
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by creationdate) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by creationdate) as seqnum_u
      from t
     ) t
group by user, (seqnum - seqnum_u);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this answer. I'm sure it would work but I feel it is a bit too much to implement using SQL. Once you add in additional filters and conditions it would be too hard to understand and maintain, so I have decided to implement the counting in application logic.